# How create Pandas DataFrame object using data from another DataFrame object?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My goal is to use this dataset

```
         mngr  shares  value ticker
0  JP Morgan      50     12   AAPL
1        AQR     120     12   AAPL
2  JP Morgan       5     30  GOOGL
3  JP Morgan       6     25     FB
4        AQR      10     30  GOOGL
5        AQR      12     25     FB
6        AQR      30     14     PG
```

to create another dataset, where the values are taken from the column "shares":

```
           AAPL  GOOGL   FB   PG
JP Morgan    50      5    6   NaN
AQR         120     10    12  30
```

So far I have an almost complete code

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'mngr': ['JP Morgan', 'AQR', 'JP Morgan', 'JP Morgan', 'AQR', 'AQR', 'AQR'], 'shares': [50, 120, 5, 6, 10, 12, 30],
'value': [12, 12, 30, 25, 30, 25, 14], 'ticker': ['AAPL', 'AAPL', 'GOOGL', 'FB', 'GOOGL', 'FB', 'PG']})
mngrlist = []
tickerlist = []
shareslist = []
for item in df.mngr.unique():
    mngrlist.append(item)
for item in df.ticker.unique():
    tickerlist.append(item)
for item in df.shares.unique():
    shareslist.append(item)
print df
r = np.zeros((len(mngrlist), len(tickerlist)))*np.nan
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=tickerlist, data=r)
df1.index = mngrlist
for s in tickerlist:
    for t in mngrlist:
        tick = df['ticker'] == s
        mn = df["mngr"] == t
        df1[s][t] = df.loc[tick & mn, "shares"].values
print df1
```

but the only problem is the last step with this line

```
df1[s][t] = df.loc[tick & mn, "shares"].values
```

As I understood, these two objects have different dimensions(natures), although if you print out every

```
df.loc[tick & mn, "shares"].values
```

it has only one element each, and I don't know how to convert it into a simple float value. I also tried to use groupby, but didn't succeed.

Another question is whether it is possible to write a more efficient code for this procedure. I will need to run it for a large dataset, so efficiency matters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If i understand correctly, you want to ["pivot"](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) the original DF:

```
In [305]: df.pivot(index='mngr', columns='ticker', values='shares')
Out[305]:
ticker      AAPL    FB  GOOGL    PG
mngr
AQR        120.0  12.0   10.0  30.0
JP Morgan   50.0   6.0    5.0   NaN
```

optionally, we can remove axis names:

```
In [307]: df.pivot(index='mngr', columns='ticker', values='shares') \
            .rename_axis(None) \
            .rename_axis(None,1)
Out[307]:
            AAPL    FB  GOOGL    PG
AQR        120.0  12.0   10.0  30.0
JP Morgan   50.0   6.0    5.0   NaN
```

Comment: Why am I so late to this question?

Comment: @Bharath, there is still one or two options left ... ;-)

Comment: Yeah we can use crosstab but pivot is the correct way of doing it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, guys! All the comments are superhelpful

Comment: @AnnaIgnashkina, glad it helps :)

Comment: I am still curious how to modify the initial code in case I want to assign some particular values from one df to the elements in another df?

Comment: @AnnaIgnashkina, in Pandas we try to avoid using loops if possible, because usually it's much slower compared to Pandas/Numpy/SciPy ufuncs. Could you open a new question and provide trhere two small input data sets, short description (describing your goals) and your desired data set? I think this is the best approach, which maximizes the probability to receive good and tested answers ;)

Answer (score 4):

Another way other than @MaxU nearly perfect solution is to use `set_index` and `unstack`:

```
df.set_index(['mngr','ticker']).unstack(1)['shares']
```

Output:

```
ticker      AAPL    FB  GOOGL    PG
mngr                               
AQR        120.0  12.0   10.0  30.0
JP Morgan   50.0   6.0    5.0   NaN
```